# Fancytree scrollIntoView when Filtered

Tags: jquery, fancytree

I am using fancyTree v2.7.0 with the filter extension.  I have enabled the autoscroll feature to scroll to the active node.

The issue I am having is when the treeview has been filtered. If you click the expand button to show an item's children, The following error message appears in the console.

```
Error: Fancytree assertion failed: scrollIntoView node is invisible
```

I have created a jsFiddle to recreate the issue http://jsfiddle.net/ajw89/86308as6/8/

Is this a Fancytree bug or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I suggest, you open an issue for it on the project page

Comment: I have opened an issue. https://github.com/mar10/fancytree/issues/391

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue. It appears only when both ***autoScroll: true*** and ***filter: {mode: "hide"}*** settings are set. If you can leave without one of these settings it works fine!

The problem arises in nodeSetExpanded() method when the auto scrolling is computed for the last child of the Node. If this child does not match the filter criteria, it is hidden by the filtering, so the .is(":visible") assertion fails.
I've fixed this locally by introducing the following method in FancytreeNode:

```
getLastVisibleChild: function() {
        var last = null;

        if (this.children) {
            for(var i=0, l=this.children.length; i<l; i++){
                if ($(this.children[i].span).is(":visible")) {
                    last = this.children[i];
                }
            }
        }

        return last;
    }
```

than I use this method in nodeSetExpanded() to replace

```
// Scroll down to last child, but keep current node visible
node.getVisibleChild().scrollIntoView(true, {topNode: node}).always(function(){
```

with

```
// Scroll down to last child, but keep current node visible
node.getLastVisibleChild().scrollIntoView(true, {topNode: node}).always(function(){
```

Works fine.